# Why does Play throw NoSuchMethodError for Netty's HttpRequest.headers() with Selendroid?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, netty, selendroid

Ok so I had my localhost:9000 working just fine one week ago and I am getting this error ever since I moved my project to Eclipse. Even when I have the code in its most basic form, it produces a Netty error that is caught by Play.

Here is my error:

```
 [info] play - Application started (Prod)
 [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
 [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.headers()Lorg/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders;
 at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.getHeaders(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:366) ~[na:na]
 at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:87) ~[na:na]
 at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[na:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:100) ~[na:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[na:na]
 [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.headers()Lorg/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders;
 at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.getHeaders(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:366) ~[na:na]
 at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:87) ~[na:na]
 at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[na:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:100) ~[na:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[na:na]
 [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.headers()Lorg/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders;
 at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.getHeaders(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:366) ~[na:na]
 at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:87) ~[na:na]
 at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[na:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:100) ~[na:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[na:na]
```

Here is the basic form code:

```
public class Application extends Controller /*implements Runnable*/ {

public static RequestBody print;
//private static RemoteWebDriver driver;
//private static int ok;

public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
}

// Step that prints the object once the JSON is received
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result receive(){
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if(json == null)
        // As long as the json is null it will display this
        return badRequest("Expecting data");
    else{
        RequestBody body = request().body();
           print = body;
           return ok("Data received.\n" + body.asJson());
    }
}

public static Result show(){
    if(print == null){
        return ok("Expecting data.");
    }
    //(new Thread(new Application())).start();
    return ok(print.asJson());
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch. Your runtime classpath doesn't contain the proper version of Netty with that particular method.

Comment: Thanks! Taking out the Selendroid jar file of the classpath made it for me. However, I want to be able to use the Selendroid.... still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `evicted` command, `exclude` and `force()` in the build with very helpful reports under `target/resolution-cache/reports/`. Don't forget about [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph).

As said in [Exclude specific transitive deps](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#exclude-specific-transitive-deps):

> Sometimes it takes a bit of detective work to figure out which transitive deps to exclude.

I've experienced the very similar issue and the solution was to use proper dependency of Netty library (or rather exclude one to let `assembly` pass).

```
[microservice]> evicted
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/work/.../}microservice...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2 -> 1.4.01 (caller: xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0, dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1)
[warn]  * io.netty:netty:(3.6.6.Final, 3.6.3.Final) -> 3.9.3.Final (caller: com.typesafe.netty:netty-http-pipelining:1.1.2, com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.3.7, org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:2.0.8, com.netflix.astyanax:astyanax-cassandra:1.56.48)
[warn]  * joda-time:joda-time:1.6.2 -> 2.3 (caller: com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.11:2.3.7, com.netflix.astyanax:astyanax-core:1.56.48, com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.3.7, com.netflix.astyanax:astyanax-cassandra:1.56.48, com.netflix.astyanax:astyanax-recipes:1.56.48, com.netflix.astyanax:astyanax-thrift:1.56.48)
[warn]  * jline:jline:1.0 -> 2.11 (caller: com.tinkerpop:gremlin-groovy:3.0.0.M6, org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:2.0.8)
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed Feb 20, 2015 6:42:14 PM
```

As you may have noticed in the above snippet, I was facing dependency version mismatch between three different versions of Netty - `3.6.6.Final`, `3.6.3.Final` and `3.9.3.Final`.

I needed `3.6.6.Final` to be chosen so I used `force()` for the version that I explicitly added to the build (using **build.sbt**):

```
libraryDependencies += "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.6.3.Final" force()
```

With the above line in the build, executing `evicted` showed:

```
[warn]  * io.netty:netty:(3.9.3.Final, 3.6.6.Final) -> 3.6.3.Final (caller: com.typesafe.netty:netty-http-pipelining:1.1.2, org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:2.0.8, com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.3.7, com.netflix.astyanax:astyanax-cassandra:1.56.48, my.company:microservice_2.11:0.6.1)
```

The build is for `my.company:microservice_2.11:0.6.1` that appeared in the above output (the very last library).

Sometimes, however, you should use `exclude` to remove conflicting dependencies as follows:

```
libraryDependencies ~= { _ map(m => m.exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging")) }
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to query whether a version of a jar defines or references a given method?

Comment: I don't know any way to do it.